# How do I plot a map in QGIS

Tags: gis, postgis, qgis

I am a beginner in qgis. I would like to know how I would plot the following map in qgis.

[image: map]

I have already installed qgis and I have the database that contains the plotting data but I'm stuck in creating maps, any help? 
Here is the sample data:

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GIpc.png)INSERT INTO public."Department"("DepartmentID","DepartmentName","PatientCount","DoctorCount","Location") VALUES('SUR','Surgery',2,2,ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((10 30 0, 10 45 0, 20 45 0, 20 30 0, 10 30 0)),((10 30 0, 10 45 0, 10 45 10, 10 30 10, 10 30 0)),((10 45 0, 20 45 0, 20 45 10, 10 45 10, 10 45 0)),((20 45 0, 20 30 0, 20 30 10, 20 45 10, 20 45 0)),((20 30 0, 10 30 0, 10 30 10, 20 30 10 ,20 30 0)),((10 30 10, 10 45 10, 20 45 10, 20 30 10, 10 30 10)))',0));
INSERT INTO public."Department"("DepartmentID","DepartmentName","PatientCount","DoctorCount","Location") VALUES('GAS','Gastroenterology',2,2,ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((10 10 0, 10 20 0, 30 20 0, 30 10 0, 10 10 0)),((10 10 0, 10 20 0, 10 20 10, 10 10 10, 10 10 0)),((10 20 0, 30 20 0, 30 20 10, 10 20 10, 10 20 0)),((30 20 0, 30 10 0, 30 10 10, 30 20 10, 30 20 0)),((30 10 0, 10 10 0, 10 10 10, 30 10 10 ,30 10 0)),((10 10 10, 10 20 10, 30 20 10, 30 10 10, 10 10 10)))',0)););
INSERT INTO public."Department"("DepartmentID","DepartmentName","PatientCount","DoctorCount","Location") VALUES('NEU','Neurology',1,1,ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((30 30 0, 30 40 0, 40 40 0, 40 30 0, 30 30 0)),((30 30 0, 30 40 0, 30 40 10, 30 40 30, 30 30 0)),((30 40 0, 40 40 0, 40 40 10, 30 40 10, 30 40 0)),((40 40 0, 40 30 0, 30 30 30, 40 40 10, 40 40 0)),((40 30 0, 30 30 0, 30 40 30, 30 30 30 ,40 30 0)),((30 40 30, 30 40 10, 40 40 10, 30 30 30, 30 40 30)))',0)););

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide reproducible example, data. error messages, issues with code. SO is not a place for supporting general activities.

Comment: Share some sample data and the table structure. Are the axes also data to plot?

Comment: As the other comments suggest, there's not enough information to answer the question. I'd suggest working through some QGIS tutorials (there are plenty online) to figure out how it works. That should give you enough knowledge to know what you don't know and allow you to better ask the question if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: @mlinth here is the table stucture and sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the more commonly used `POLYGON` to store my shapes and make sure that you have added a `geometryColumn` to the table using either:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','my_spatial_table','locations',0,'POLYGON',2, false);
```

or more simply with any PostGIS version 2+:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN locations geometry(Point,0);
```

Note I've used the SRID of 0 here (you will often see values of 4326 in the examples) as you don't appear to have a projection for your coordinates. Once you have "registered" the geometry column QGIS will recognise the table as a spatial one and you can just drag and drop it into the canvas from the browser.

In general questions about QGIS usage (rather than programming) are better asked on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).